# Regex in cfif to check there's a parameter in URL?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to display a block of code only if the parameter ?staff is appended to URL, e.g.:

display Link only if the current URL was loaded with www.blank.com/folder/?staff

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the url with a regex, It should be in the url variable already if defined

```
<cfif IsDefined("URL.staff")>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is any kind of performance difference, but to me it's best practices to use `StructKeyExists(url,'staff')` rather than `isDefined("url.staff")`. Either one will definitely get the job done though.

Comment: Generally StructureKeyExists is preferred because it is more precise. IsDefined [casts a very wide net](http://coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2009/8/6/examining.isDefined) in its search for variables which can sometimes introduce ambiguity - not to mention [confusion](http://corfield.org/entry/isDefined_vs_structKeyExists).